# How do I use GREP to match a string with quotation marks inside it?

Tags: macos, grep

I'm looking for a string match inside a group of HTML files. I'm looking for all matching instances of the form:

```
="https://  ...  .mp4"
```

Keep in mind that these are not on individual lines. They are all bunched together without any spaces, so returning actual lines won't work.

I want GREP to return all grouped instances of this type of URL. I'm wanting an output of unique links like this:

```
="https://www.something.com/file1.mp4"
="https://www.something.com/file2.mp4"
="https://www.something.com/file3.mp4"
="https://www.something.com/file4.mp4"
```

Here's the search parameter, as I thought I would need:

```
grep -hRo '\="https://.*\.mp4"\>' *.html
```

The double quotes and equal sign should be a part of the actual search string, but those are messing up my result, and I can't figure out how to escape them properly.

I'm running this on OSX in the terminal. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What about the ".mp4"?

Comment: Utterly avoid the GNU grep `-R` and `-r` options and anything else related to finding files with grep. Simply use `find` to **find** files and `grep` to **g/re/p** within files (yes, there are big clues in the names of the tools as to what they are designed to do!) and you'll be much happier for it (as will anyone else reading your code later!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With traditional regex, the double quotes are escaped by the single quotes. You only need to escape the quantifier `+` (one or more) and the literal dot in `.mp4`

```
grep -o '="http[^"]\+\.mp4"'
```

With PCRE, available in GNU Grep, you can actually match (without printing) the leading/trailing equals/doublequotes with Lookarounds:

```
grep -Po '(?<==")http[^"]+\.mp4(?=")'
```

- `(?<= ... )` - lookbehind
- `(?=  ... )` - lookahead

returns:

```
https://www.something.com/file1.mp4
https://www.something.com/file2.mp4
https://www.something.com/file3.mp4
https://www.something.com/file4.mp4
```

Comment: Is that a "look ahead" flag? Can you tell me a bit about how that works?

Comment: @PatrickHennessey Just updated; please let me know if it's still unclear. [Gory details](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: Ok, one more question: how do I search inside of all .html files in a directory, recursively? I tried using -r but it just says "no such file or directory: grep -hor '"http[^"]\+\.mp4"' *.html

Comment: `find . -type f -exec grep -o '="http[^"]\+\.mp4"' {} \;` will search in current dir

Comment: And what does [^"] mean?

Comment: it means , any character except `"` . if you want to read more about it , google character classes in regex